# Error installing create-react-app with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, create-react-app

When I try to install create-react-app (or nodemon) globally or even within a project, I get the following error. However, I can install other packages perfectly fine both globally and locally. I think it has something to do with the fact that both create-react-app and nodemon are run from the terminal rather than used within a project's code.

I have already tried reinstalling nodejs and opening the terminal as administrator, but that did not work.

```
$ npm i -D nodemon
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\78\49\9aac8fdb9b898c6d95e47da44f0425e95568d85f83d82f7bae06293b0a03
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\78\49\9aac8fdb9b898c6d95e47da44f0425e95568d85f83d82f7bae06293b0a03'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-22T13_29_35_317Z-debug.log
```

---

UPDATE: When I ran npm cache clean --force, I got the following error

```
$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\78
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, unlink 'C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\78'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-22T13_55_42_508Z-debug.log
```

Comment: For create react app try `npx create-react-app appname`, have you tried including `sudo` in front of the terminal commands?

Comment: I get the same error using npx. I am on Windows 10, so I can't sudo, but I have tried to run as admin which had no result.

Comment: Below the error, it also said:
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 4294963202

Comment: @ShivangPatel did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Sikandar Sadly, no I did not.

Comment: @ShivangPatel, posted my solution below which worked for me.

Comment: Try this answer; it worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657920/i-cant-install-react-using-npx-create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm cache clean --force` and then try installing again

Comment: I got an error when running this command. Check my question for more details (I updated it).

Comment: @ShivangPatel delete the npm-cache found in this path: `C:\Users\Shivang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` and try again. This is definitely cache related issue

Comment: For some reason, I can't delete the folder. I tried right clicking and then clicking delete but that didn't work. I even tried dragging to the recycling bin, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @ShivangPatel then may be some virus infection or admin permission issues. Try again after restarting

Comment: I restarted and ran as admin, but it didn't make a difference. I am going to run a virus scanner right now.

Comment: I ran Avast and Malware-bytes but they didn't find any viruses. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @ShivangPatel sorry nothing else. Your solution involves that npm-cache folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185658/discussion-between-shivang-patel-and-sansolo).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to execute the command as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Found a solution for the same.

- Go to C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
- Delete all items present there
- Some files inside 1 or more folders you may not be able to delete, then just rename them 
  to some random name.
- Now retry npm install. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And then

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`npx`
command instead of
`npm`

Like this,
First Mkdir appName
`mkdir appName`
Secondly Cd into the app
`cd appName`

Thirdly run npx
`npx create-react-app ./`

This how to run npx in react 18

Answer (score 0):

Lol i just took the two previous answers and put them together. So the solution is:

npm cache clean --force (-g if first try doesnt work after npx).
then just use npx instead of npm.