# NPM Install error In laravel and vue js app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm-install

[image]

I am facing this error while install npm in laravel app
I also run it as administratively But did not work

If anybody could help that would be great

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing create-react-app with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896092/error-installing-create-react-app-with-npm)

Comment: Hi @Rezwan, could you please add the error message that you get as text, then it will be searchable in Stackoverflow and Google? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename existing node_modules folder and install again