# Error! While creating new react native project

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I am creating new react native project using `npx react-native init <project_name>`, I'm getting this error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
> npm ERR! syscall lstat
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\fb\f4\de4554e8003a503d2a6bb0f9308bd298f31eb861cb89a63ccc055212c163fe696cec203b96266c8c5d3003942836101309a8947b6e7d56fc891fcd544258
> npm ERR! errno -4094
> npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\fb\f4\de4554e8003a503d2a6bb0f9308bd298f31eb861cb89a63ccc055212c163fe696cec203b96266c8c5d3003942836101309a8947b6e7d56fc891fcd544258'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-19T10_19_25_306Z-debug.log
> Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 4294963202
> ```

I have updated the node js as well but getting the same error again and again.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[Error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfCZ7.png)

Comment: Please consider using proper format console command/output using code block

Comment: a similar topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896092/error-installing-create-react-app-with-npm