# How to run npx with something similar to `--registry https://registry.npmjs.org` when running npm install to get around artifactory?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

`--registry https://registry.npmjs.org` is been used to get around artifactory alike proxy when install with `npm install` But I want to do similiar thing with `npm xxx` because I encounter

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
```

when try to do `npx create-react-app myapp`

Is that something possible?

I literarily can't find any info about this online!

Comment: solutions in this answer might hep you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657920/i-cant-install-react-using-npx-create-react-app

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run something like:

```sh
npm_config_registry=https://registry.npmjs.org npx xxx
```

This is [suggested](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/133#issuecomment-348684449) by the npm team. I ran into this same problem, but that was because I needed to have npx point to a private registry.