# I got this error while creating react app.It is showing that it is deleting app instead of creating

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I got this error. I have done same as given in documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install react using npx create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657920/i-cant-install-react-using-npx-create-react-app)

Comment: its best to put the code and error directly as text. as much as possible avoid error showing with images.

Answer (score 0):

First run the following command.

`npm cache clean --force`

Then try again . If it is a local caching issue then it should work :D