# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "12.x". Got "14.8.0"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package, yarnpkg, package.json

I try to do a `yarn add`, but I have this error:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "12.x". Got "14.8.0"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can suggest 2 solutions :

**1/** ***It works but it's probably not the best way***

You just have to update your packages.json.

currently :

```
 "engines": {
     "node": "12.x"
 }
```

updated :

```
 "engines": {
     "node": "14.8.0"
 }
```

**2/** ***I think it's a cleaner way***

You can use `nvm use x` to use the Node version.

exemple : `nvm use 14` to use node version 14

Maybe you have to run :`nvm install 14` before

Answer (score 20):

Run these commands:

```sh
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then in your project directory run:

```sh
rm -r ./node_modules
rm ./yarn.lock
```

After this, `yarn install | add | upgrade` should work as expected.

P.S. If you are using the `npm` package manager, instead of `rm ./yarn.lock` run `rm ./package-lock.json`.

Comment: what does `npm install -g n` do? Does n refer to node? And how does that interact with setting node via nvm?

Comment: @Hyetigran The "n" package is a Node.js version management utility that allows you to easily switch between different versions of Node.js on your system. Once you have installed "n", you can use it to install or switch to a different version of Node.js by typing "n <version>" in your terminal. For example, "n 14.17.6" would install or switch to version 14.17.6 of Node.js. In this case "n stable" switches to the latest stable Node version.

Answer (score 14):

One time fix for the "the engine node is incompatible with this module" problem.

```
$ yarn install --ignore-engines
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I try to make a new app with react. When I do `npx create-react-app my-app`,
I get this error:

> babel-jest@27.4.5: the engine "node" is incompatible with this module. expected version "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0". got "14.8.0"
> I solved this problem with this  which I found this on other stockoverflow  answer.
> [I can't install react using npx create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657920/i-cant-install-react-using-npx-create-react-app)

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

This may help you.