# Engine incompatible error while deploying react app to cloudflare pages

Tags: reactjs, build, cloudflare, yarn-v2, cloudflare-pages

I am trying to deploy my react app on cloudflare pages and getting this error while building with yarn.

error got@12.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.16". Got "12.18.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error during Yarn install
Failed: build command exited with code: 1
Failed: error occurred while running build command

The build is successful in my local, I am using node version v16.15.0
It seems like cloudflare is using lower node version 12 by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "12.x". Got "14.8.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429081/the-engine-node-is-incompatible-with-this-module-expected-version-12-x-got)

Answer (score 1):

The required node version for your application is greater than 14.16 as specified by the error statement.
As of 25 April 2023, **Cloudflare has default Node version as Node.js   12.18.0**

We can change the node version by setting the **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE** during the build process.

Setting **NODE_VERSION** = 16.15.0 will solve the issue.