# Building expo app failed The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18". Got "16.18.1"

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native, thus I'm using ignite as template. I'm using the expo environment, I want to try to build the ignite app immediately after installing it. However I got an error on the install dependencies step.

Steps to reproduce:

1. npx ignite-cli@latest new DriverTab --yes
2. eas build (android)

The build failed

```
Running "yarn install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build directory

yarn install v1.22.17

[1/5] Validating package.json...

[stderr] 

error driver-tab@0.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18". Got "16.18.1"

[stderr] 

error Found incompatible module.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

Error: Unknown error. See logs for more information.
```

i tried checking the node version and it says 18.16.1, but somehow it's 16.18.1, I've tried solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429081/the-engine-node-is-incompatible-with-this-module-expected-version-12-x-got) but still got this error (including trying the yarn install --ignore-engines).

i've tried the ignite-cli expo doctor and it says i'm using the 18.16.1

```
System
  platform           win32
  arch               x64
  cpu                16 cores     AMD Ryzen 7 6800HS with Radeon Graphics
  directory          DriverTab    D:\DriverTab

JavaScript (and globally-installed packages)
  node               18.16.1      
  npm                9.5.1        
    eas-cli          4.1.2
    expo-cli         6.3.10
    pod-install      0.1.39
    yarn             1.22.19
  yarn               1.22.19      
  expo               48.0.20      managed

Ignite
  ignite-cli         8.8.7        
  ignite src         build        

Android
  java               18.0.1.1     
  android home       -            undefined

Tools
  git                git version 2.39.0.windows.2   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE
```

Is there anyone who have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've also used ignite-cli to create an app and got the same error.

I was able to fix it by replacing node version inside package.json :

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=18"
},
```

with

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=16"
},
```

I don't like this fix but at least it works.