# Is there a way to get npx to create a React app on my computer?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

I am totally new to React and Node.js although I have written software in a variety of languages and have created web applications using Cold Fusion. I am using Windows 10 Home Edition 64 bit. I purchased Robin Wieruch's book and followed the instructions to download Node.js, React and Visual Studio Code. When I typed in npx create-react-app hacker, I got errors and tried various fixes from youtube videos. No success. The code is below. Is there a fix or work around?

```
C:\Users\Warren\Documents\proj>npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f
removed 66 packages in 1.335s
C:\Users\warre\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\warre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
C:\Users\warre\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\warre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
+ npm@7.19.1
added 256 packages from 146 contributors in 13.76s
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

C:\Users\Warren\Documents\proj>npx create-react-app hacker
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y
(node:11992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Warren\Documents\proj\hacker'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:1009:3)
    at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\warre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:101:15)
    at createApp (C:\Users\warre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:255:6)
    at C:\Users\warre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:226:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11992) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't install react using npx create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657920/i-cant-install-react-using-npx-create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

[On GitHub](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/209#issuecomment-450702301), someone solved the same problem you're having,

> EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir  ...

by running

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app
```

– i.e. installing `create-react-app` globally first.

Comment: I tried but no success. The npm install worked but the npx create... did not.

Comment: had this issues and that helped me very strange and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was almost trivial. I looked at the properties for the project folder in which I wanted to create the new React app. I modified the write permissions for users and the system to enable writing. The npx create-react-app my-app worked without a hitch. Thanks all. I hope this helps someone else. I should have realized that when the MkDir operation failed, it was a read/write issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

First create new folder (app name)

````
```Mkdir appName```
````

Secondly Cd into your new app
`Cd appName`
Thirdly run your npx command
`npx create-react-app ./`

It will work