# Unable to create a react app even after clearing severity vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to create a webpage using Reactjs (for learning react js).

After I run the command `npx create-react-app cars`, I'm getting errors as follows:

> ```
> npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
> added 64 packages, and audited 107 packages in 15s
> 3 high severity vulnerabilities
> To address all issues, run:
> npm audit fix
> Run "npm audit" for details.
> ```

After running `npm audit`, it says:

> ```
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: npm audit fix --force
> ```

which gave the result as:

> ```
> found 0 vulnerabilities
> ```

After following all these steps, when I try to create a project starting from `create-react-app` I'm getting same errors like:

> ```
> x high severity vulnerabilities to address all issues, run: npm audit
> ```

I don't understand what I'm missing here. By all these I ended up creating 4 folders which has a subfolder `node-modules` and two JSON files named `package` and `package-lock`

Can anybody please direct me how do I proceed with all these?

- npm version: 7.21.0
- node version: v16.7.0
- windows: 10

Comment: See the last para of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68882901/9256189) answer.

Comment: @TechySharnav that gives me "'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @TechySharnav I'm also unsure if this is what causing the issue here i.stack.imgur.com/X9x0h.png

Comment: There is a possibility ByteFence is causing the issue. Try disabling it before running the command. For the `create-react-app` issue, you need to install it using `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: @TechySharnav Thank you for guiding. It is working completely fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps I followed to create my react environment and get ride of these warnings/errors are:

1. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529411/16748919), I have uninstalled ByteFence since as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920694/unable-to-create-a-react-app-even-after-clearing-severity-vulnerabilities#comment121805655_68920694) in the comments that there a threat detection 
    and
2. Used this command `npm set audit false` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755352/16748919)

Apart from these steps, I made sure that I have latest versions of Node and npm installed