# i am getting an error when creating a react app using npx

Tags: reactjs

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Error:
We no longer support the global installation of Create React App.
Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

I tried

```
 npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then

```
 npx create-react-app my-app
```

but it still gives me the same error
node --version v14.17.6
npm --version 8.1.1

Comment: Try to run this maybe it will fix that

$ npm cache verify
$ npm clean cache --force

Answer (score 0):

Try this out i am having the same problem and fixed it ny cleaning cache and then run npx create-react-app my-app

```
npm cache clean --force
npx create-react-app myapp
```

for further guidance check out this previous answer

[I can't install react using npx create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657920/i-cant-install-react-using-npx-create-react-app)

you can also check offical documentation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app